# Probability question: Gambler's problem

Tags: probability

> A  and  B  play  a  fair  game  (i.e.  winning  probability  is ½  for
>   both  players) repeatedly   for   one   rupee   per   game.   If
>   originally   A has **a** rupees   and   B has **b** rupees  (where 
>   a>b),  what  is  A's  chances  of  winning  all  of  B's  money,
>   assuming the play goes on until one person has lost all her money?
>
> a)1
>
> (b) 0
>
> (c) b/(a+b)
>
> (d) a/(a+b)

Please help with this.I am having difficulty understanding the concept.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin

Comment: Even without knowing the problem itself... given that this is a multiple choice question, if you were to assume that the correct answer is among the choices given to you this should be easily found via process of elimination.  Clearly, the probability cannot be $1$ or $0$ because it is possible for either player to emerge the overall victor, each with positive probability.  Next, the only question is whether you think it should be $(c)$ or $(d)$.  **Intuitively**, since $A$ starts out with more money than $B$, do you expect $A$ to be the overall winner *more* or *less* often than $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a multiple choice questions let's break it down to look at each of the possible answers.

A. 1
This cannot be the right answer because it isn't very logical that if they both have an equal chance to win, it will be guaranteed for anyone.

B. 0
Same as A, it isn't guaranteed

C. a/(a+b)
This is what i believe is the correct answer because broken down ot looks like 'amount of money A has / total amount'. Here it is in a simple example; A has 2 rupees, B has 1 Rupee the equation will look like 
2/(2+1) = 2/3 chance of winning

D. b/(a+b)
This is what the B's odds of winning would be (pun totally intended)

Hope that this helps!

**EDIT** It really doesn't matter who starts out with more money, just saying.